# form_for nested resource with changed name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have two models:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stories, class_name: 'ProjectStory'
end

class ProjectStory
  belongs_to :project
end
```

with the following routes:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :stories
end
```

All the controllers are set correctly. Now, I have a `stories/_form` partial (which is to be reused for both new and edit) with the following line:

```
= form_for [@story.project, @story] do
```

The problem is however, that `@story.model_name.singular_route_name` returns `project_story` and hence it is trying to execute `project_project_name_path` to calculate form url. This, obviously, raising `no method error`.

I could override it with `url` option, however I would need to use ternary operator to handle both `edit` and `new` cases:

```
= form_for @story, url: @story.new_record? ? project_stories_path(@story.project) : project_story_path(@story.project, @story)
```

Is there any way to let rails know that it should use different name for a single element of the nested route? I would prefer not to rename my models or controllers (to avoid those annoying url helpers like `edit_project_project_story_path`)

Comment: `project_project_name_path` -- here what is `name` ?

Comment: `= form_for [@story.project, @story] do` what HTML is generated by this line?

Comment: @R_O_R - my bad, it is executing project_project_story_path

Comment: @test it is not generating anything but exception.

Comment: try to use `= form_for project_project_story_path(@project, @story)`

Comment: This will make form_builders object a string, which will fail on to model conversion.

Comment: do you have @project object?